# Clarifying who decides memory mappings and port IO mappings

Tags: linux-kernel, driver, device-driver, kernel

I studied a bit about port mapped IO and memory mapped IO and I figured out how the first works (not the second yet), so if you have something well-explained about how memory mapped IO is performed (I heard it's about intercepting page faults by the OS to reroute them to the devices) please let me know.

Anyway my question is: communicating with the internal real time clock (RTS) uses an I/O Port mapping and you need to use outb(byte_selected,0x70) and similar functions on the 0x70 port.. who decided the 0x70 port? How can I figure out where are they declared? And what about memory mapping IOs? Who decides what addresses are associated to what devices? And if I added my own device to the system, how would its memory be mapped?

I've still a lot of confusion about OS-hw communications..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory mappings are decided by the hardware manufacturer and are hardwired on the bus. They cannot be changed whatsoever and the correct mappings must be read from the hardware specification.

Some pluggable buses like PCI work by having their own address space for their devices. They can detect the presence of devices and their needs in terms of I/O and assign them ranges within this reserved space. The CPU can then access it through its own space using PCI registers, or more efficiently through DMA. See this page for more details: http://tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/pci.html

Note that not all devices work with mapped I/O - for instance, USB devices do not use memory I/O and only communicate with the host through well-defined USB commands.

Comment: Note though that the USB host controller generally *does* use memory-mapped I/O to generate those commands. Note also: the example using `outb` is port-based I/O, which is a special x86 feature that is distinct from memory-mapped I/O. It's a legacy thing, and those mappings are completely hard-wired.

Comment: Great point I forgot to mention. int/outb do not use memory mapping, but their own 16-bits address space. This is very legacy stuff and not so used nowadays, except for basic configuration on x86. Once again mapping is statically decided, although some very old ISA cards (sound blaster, gravis ultrasound...) allowed you to change the I/O ports they used as well (as the IRQ and DMA) using jumpers. PCI and its automatic configuration rendered this useless　(and PCI uses its own address space too).